# How to parse soap response having href tag using pl/sql

Tags: xml, soap, plsql, xml-parsing

I want to parse the below soap response. The problem is in tag1, its point to a href link called id1. So we have to go to the response of id1 and get the value.

And one more thing is this soap response value is change the sequence in each request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getBlock soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://diamondip.com/ipcontrol/ws/">
        <getBlockByIpAddressReturn href="#id0"/>
    </ns1:getBlock>

<multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:WSGenericBlock" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://service.ipcontrol.diamondip.com">
    <tag1 href="#id1"/>      
    <tag2 soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
        <item xsi:type="soapenc:string">Container1</item>
    </tag2>  
    <tag3 xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T06:45:32.000Z</tag3>
    <tag4 soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[4]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
        <item xsi:type="soapenc:string">uf1=221805</item>
        <item xsi:type="soapenc:string">uf2=34531</item>
    </tag4> 
    <tag5 href="#id2"/> 
</multiRef>   
<multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:boolean" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">false</multiRef>
<multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" lowestSetBit="3" xsi:type="soapenc:integer" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">8</multiRef>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can give you a start (it's not perfect, I know...)

```
declare

  xl clob := '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getBlock soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://diamondip.com/ipcontrol/ws/">
        <getBlockByIpAddressReturn href="#id0"/>
    </ns1:getBlock>

<multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:WSGenericBlock" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://service.ipcontrol.diamondip.com">
    <tag1 href="#id1"/>      
    <tag2 soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
        <item xsi:type="soapenc:string">Container1</item>
    </tag2>  
    <tag3 xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T06:45:32.000Z</tag3>
    <tag4 soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[4]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
        <item xsi:type="soapenc:string">uf1=221805</item>
        <item xsi:type="soapenc:string">uf2=34531</item>
    </tag4> 
    <tag5 href="#id2"/> 
</multiRef>   
<multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:boolean" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">false</multiRef>
<multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" lowestSetBit="3" xsi:type="soapenc:integer" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">8</multiRef>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

  v_parser Xmlparser.Parser;
  v_doc    XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
  v_nl     XMLDOM.DOMNodeList;
  v_att    varchar2(300);
  v_refId  varchar2(300);
  v_val    varchar2(300);

begin

  v_parser := Xmlparser.newParser;
  xmlparser.setValidationMode(v_parser, TRUE);

  Xmlparser.parseClob(v_parser, xl);

  v_doc := Xmlparser.getDocument(v_parser);

  v_nl  := xslprocessor.selectNodes(XMLDOM.makeNode(v_doc), '//tag1');
  v_att := XMLDOM.getAttribute((XMLDOM.makeElement(XMLDOM.item(v_nl, 0))),
                               'href');

  v_refId := substr(v_att, 2);

  v_nl := xslprocessor.selectNodes(XMLDOM.makeNode(v_doc),
                                   '//multiRef[@id="' || v_refId || '"]');

  v_val := XMLDOM.getNodeValue(XMLDOM.getFirstChild(XMLDOM.item(v_nl, 0)));

  dbms_output.put_line(v_val);

end;
```